# How to find the current transfer function of this circuit?

Tags: current, current-source

I need the formula to find the current transfer function I have put a photo of the formula that I tried to use but it didn't work.

[image: this is the circuit I need help with finding the current transfer function]

[image: I tried to do it this way but it dose not work this way]

Answer (score 0):

I've re-derived the 2nd formula in your answer, and it seems correct. That was the only thing that looked suspicious to me. The rest looks fine.

Why do you think that "it didn't work"?

The parallel resistance of C<sub>o</sub> and R<sub>o</sub>

$$\begin{aligned}
R_T &= Z(C_o) || Z(R_o) = \frac{Z(C_o)Z(R_o)}{Z(C_o)+Z(R_o)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{R_o}{C_os}}{\frac{1}{C_os}+R_o} = \frac{R_o}{1+R_oC_os}.
\end{aligned}$$

Then, using the current divider formula for the right half of the circuit,

$$\begin{aligned}I_o &= -\beta I_b \frac{R_T}{R_L+R_T} = -\beta I_b \frac{\frac{R_o}{1+R_oC_os}} {R_L+\frac{R_o}{1+R_oC_os}} \\
&= -\beta I_b \frac{\frac{R_o}{1+R_oC_os}} {\frac{R_L(1+R_oC_os)+R_o}{1+R_oC_os}}
=-\beta I_b\frac{R_o}{R_o+R_L+R_LR_oC_os} \\
&= -\beta I_b \frac {1} {1+\frac{R_L}{R_o}+R_LC_os}.
\end{aligned}$$